# Why does qsort produce different output for same array but different ordering?

Tags: c, sorting, comparison, function-definition, qsort

I am trying to sort an array in descending order with the help of `qsort` in C.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int compareFloat(const void* p1, const void* p2){
    const float* pa = p1;
    const float* pb = p2;
    return pb - pa;
}

int main()
{
    float arr[] = {1.5, 1.6, 1.38};
    qsort(arr, 3, sizeof(float), compareFloat);
    printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for above code is "1.60 1.38 1.50", which is wrong; but, when the array is initialized as `float arr[] = {1.38, 1.6, 1.5}`, the answer is correct (i.e. "1.6, 1.5, 1.38").

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return value of your `compareFloat` function is wrong … for **two** reasons.

First, you are subtracting pointers, rather than the values they point to – so you would need `*pb - *pa`.

But, even then, your test will fail for values like `1.6` and `1.5`, because the result of that subtraction will be non-zero **but less than one**. Thus, when converted to the `int` return type, the function will return `0` (signalling that the values are the same), even though they are not.

You need to return the result of at least *two* comparisons:

```c
int compareFloat(const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    const float* pa = p1;
    const float* pb = p2;
    return (*pa < *pb) - (*pa > *pb);
}
```

Comment: @user3386109 I stole your code and edited my answer. However, I also *fixed* your code, because the OP wants the array in decreasing order.

Answer (score 3):

In the comparison function

```
int compareFloat(const void* p1, const void* p2){
    const float* pa = p1;
    const float* pb = p2;
    return pb - pa;
}
```

you are returning a difference of two pointers. But you need to compare the pointed values instead of the pointers itself.

The function can look the following way

```
int compareFloat( const void* p1, const void* p2)
{
    float a = *( const float * )p1;
    float b = *( const float * )p2;

    return ( a < b ) - ( b < a );
}
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compareFloat( const void *p1, const void *p2 )
{
    float a = *( const float * )p1;
    float b = *( const float * )p2;

    return ( a < b ) - ( b < a );
}

int main( void )
{
    float arr[] = { 1.5, 1.6, 1.38 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    qsort( arr, N, sizeof( float ), compareFloat );

    printf( "%.2f %.2f %.2f\n", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] );
}
```

The program output is

```
1.60 1.50 1.38
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison routine is incorrect.

```
return pb - pa;
```

Here you're subtracting the two pointer values.

If you were working with integers you would instead subtract the numbers the pointers point to:

```
return *pb - *pa;
```

But this won't work for floating point numbers due to truncation of the fractional part.  You'll need to explicitly compare and return the proper value.

```
if (*pa > *pb) {
    return -1;
} else if (*pa < *pb) {
    return 1;
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have well pointed out 2 deficiencies:

- OP's pointer subtraction should be a floating point FP subtraction/compare.
- Result needs to be an `int`.

  ```
  int compareFloat(const void* p1, const void* p2){
    const float* pa = p1;
    const float* pb = p2;
    // return pb - pa;
    return (*pb > *pa) - (*pb < *pa);
  }
  ```

There is another issue: If either FP value may be a not-a-number [NAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN), additional concerns apply to keep the compare compliant.  We need a sort that returns the opposite sign when the arguments are reversed.  Also if `a > b` and `b > c`, then `a > c`.  `(*pb > *pa) - (*pb < *pa)` above does not achieve that with NANs.

```
int compareFloat(const void* p1, const void* p2){
  const float f1 = *(const float *)p1;
  const float f2 = *(const float *)p2;
  if (isnan(f1)) {
    if (isnan(f2)) {
      // Since both are NA, just compare bit patterns
      return memcmp(p1, p2, sizeof (float));
    }
    return 1; // Consider NAN < all non-NANs
  }
  if (isnan(f2)) {
    return -1;
  }
  return (f2 > f1) - (f2 < f1);
}

int main() {
  float arr[] = {1.5f, 1.6f, NAN, 1.38f};  // Better to use float constants
  qsort(arr, 4, sizeof(float), compareFloat);
  printf("%.2f %.2f %.2f %.2f", arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
1.60 1.50 1.38 nan
```